# Is possible pass SafetyNet with official Xposed Framework?

Tags: magisk, xposed-framework, safety-net

I know LSPosed passes SafetyNet on Magisk but I want pass SafetyNet on official Xposed Framework.

Is possible with modules like HiddenCore, or maybe a snet.jar or framework patching trick?

Answer (score 0):

Official Xposed is dead since years (sadly). So No hope in doing these things via it...

Comment: I don't think bypassing SafetyNet was ever possibly by using Xposed. So the question is if it is possible to pass SafetyNet on a device with Xposed installed, by modifying the system or a Magical plugin or something completely different.

Comment: @Robert Sorry to say, but you're wrong... LSposed, which is literally an Xposed fork but still being developed has modules based on Xposed framework to pass safetynet!